# How to keep animated views on top of others?

Tags: android, animation, view

I'm trying to animate a translation of a certain view:

```
// Set view to its original starting point.
mView.setTranslationX(mDeltaLeft);
mView.setTranslationY(mDeltaTop);

// Animate a translation to view's ending point.
mView.animate().setDuration(500)
        .translationX(0)
        .translationY(0)
        .setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator());
```

The problem is that throughout this translation, this view is being obscured by other views in the layout, even if I call `setAlpha(0)` on them. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Perhaps the `View` animates out of its `ViewGroup`? (If you have multiple `ViewGroup`s on top of eachother containing the animated `View`)

Comment: It does translate out of its own `ViewGroup` - is that a limitation of animations in Android? If so, it sounds like I will have to redesign my layout such that its parent ViewGroup is the entire window - perhaps using a RelativeLayout instead of the LinearLayouts I currently have. Does that sound right?

Comment: use ViewGroup.setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled()

Comment: @sigmabeta A child cannot draw outside its parent (correct me if I'm wrong). You might want to do your suggestion indeed. Perhaps test this theory out before rewriting your layout if that is time consuming ;)

Comment: It was actually a change I was thinking of implementing anyway; it was not time consuming, and it did in fact produce the correct behavior.

If you submit what you said as an answer, I'll accept it.